# C# windows to C# phone windows

Tags: c#, windows, web-services, silverlight, windows-phone-8

This is more a task to ask than help but... after 1 day of tries I can't get it work.
This is my code

```
private string _InetReadEx(string sUrl)
        {

            HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(sUrl);
            try
            {
                webReq.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                webReq.Method = "GET";
                using (WebResponse response = webReq.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                        aRet = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        return aRet;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }

        }
```

What this code does is simple. It returns the source of a server.
So here is my silly question; how can I do something similar on C# windows phone(windows phone 8.1/8)?

Thank you in advance,
Maria

Comment: What's the specific error you're getting? Can you provide a bit more detail of this issue?

Comment: Well webReq.GetResponse()) doesn't exist in windows phone... That is the main problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use the [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh781239.aspx) I have used it both in Windows / Win Phone projects and works like a charm, have a look at [this](http://www.jayway.com/2012/03/13/httpclient-makes-get-and-post-very-simple/) too

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
webReq.BeginGetResponse(GetResponseCallback, request);

void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
    if (request != null)
    {
       try
       {
        WebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(result);
        // use response 
       }
       catch (WebException e)
       {
        return;
       }
   }
}
```