# GET : Getting an http response in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, http, get, win-universal-app

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("[URL here]");
WebResponse rep = req.GetResponse();
```

I wanted some insights into the relevance of the GetResponse method, it appears to deprecated now.

This other method I hacked together gets the job done.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(String.Format("http://mywebservicehere/dostuff?url=https://www.website.com"));
request.Method = "GET";

using (var response = (HttpWebResponse) (await Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null)))
{                
    var encoding = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII;
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding);
}
```

Wanted to know of any alternative methods others may have used? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32031181/3134635

Comment: `new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync` , `httpClient.GetStringAsync`

Comment: Thanks all, I will take a look at the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wanted some insights into the relevance of the GetResponse method,
>   it appears to deprecated now.

It is not deprecated, in the .NET for UWP, is is an async method.

```
    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("[URL here]");

    WebResponse rep = await req.GetResponseAsync();
```

> Wanted to know of any alternative methods others may have used?

Besides the WebRequest class, there are another 2 HttpClient classes in the Windows Runtime Platform you can use to get a http response.

```
    var client1 = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

    var client2 = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();
```

The System.Net.Http.HttpClient is in the .NET for UWP.
The Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient is in the Windows Runtime.